# Adding 7-digit and 10-digit dialing using the Cisco SPA122

Tags: networking, voip, voice, cisco-router

I am using the Cisco SPA122 ATA adapter with my home phone. My phone provider (CallCentric) provides instructions on how to setup the adapter, but their instructions only demonstrate 11-digit dialing. Here is their provided dial plan:

```
(*xxx|*75xx|[49]11|0|00|1xxx[2-9]xxxxxxS0|xxxxxxxxxxxx.|**275*x.)
```

I am doing outbound calls to domestic numbers almost exclusively. I would like to support 7-digit and 10-digit dialing, and skip punching in the country code and even the local exchange.

Here is the main help documentation I was able to find on Cisco dialplans:

- [Cisco Small Business SPA300 Series, SPA500 Series, and WIP310 IP Phone and Administration Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/csbpipp/ip_phones/administration/guide/frame_source/500-series-7-5-7/ip_phone_admin/shared_Dial_Plan.html)
- [Dialplan for Linksys ATAs](https://wiki.voip.ms/article/Dial_Plan_for_Linksys_ATAs)

After reading those, I made the following attempts:

```
(*xxx|*75xx|[49]11|0|00|1xxx[2-9]xxxxxxS0|<:1>xxx[2-9]xxxxxxS0|<:1717>[2-9]xxxxxxS0|xxxxxxxxxxxx.|**275*x.)
(*xxx|*75xx|[49]11|0|00|<:1>xxx[2-9]xxxxxxS0|<:1717>[2-9]xxxxxxS0|1xxx[2-9]xxxxxxS0|xxxxxxxxxxxx.|**275*x.)
```

However, neither works, and both break 11-digit dialing. What am I doing wrong?

```
Model: SPA122, LAN, 2 FXS
Firmware: 1.2.1
```

Comment: One other thing, slightly off-topic: previously was using the Grandstream HandyTone HT802. And while you can modify the dialplan and inject characters onto these stupid devices, there are horrendous limitations, and 7-digit and 10-digit dialing do not work! I was assured the Cisco/Linksys routers allow for more flexibility with dialplans, and have really enjoyed using them so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some further reading on the [Interdigit Short Timer](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/csbpipp/ip_phones/administration/guide/frame_source/500-series-7-5-7/ip_phone_admin/shared_Dial_Plan.pdf) *(pdf)* really shed some light on this.

Apparently, the `S0` at the end allows you to specify how much time you have to punch another digit before a match is applied. I foolishly applied a zero timer to several similar sequences.

Removing the timer from my own custom 7-digit and 10-digit plans resolved all problems:

```
(*xxx|*75xx|[49]11|0|00|<:1>xxx[2-9]xxxxxx|<:1717>[2-9]xxxxxx|1xxx[2-9]xxxxxxS0|xxxxxxxxxxxx.|**275*x.)
```

Comment: Long live the 717 area code!